# Try Google Cloud Messaging Always Fail

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I started with this link

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

I have problem on step 4. I can show *"Token retrieved and sent to server! You can now use gcmsender to send downstream messages to this app"* on the device.

But when I run **.\gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=""**

It always give me **Task 'run' not found in root project**

What am I missing here?

Comment: there is no `run` gradle task, and that's what the error is telling you ... ?

Comment: To send a downstream messages to app, you should use GCM api https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send with your api key

Comment: @Shark, yes that's right gradle task has no run. But the link I gave above on step 4, it says to execute run. I confused.

Comment: @IndraKumarS, yes I think so but before setting up Server side, I just finished with client side. But why it says to execute gradlew.bat run -Pmsg=""